# uso de bucle while

Tags: string, condiciones, while, else, scanner

```
package BucleWhile;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio10 {
    /* Desarrollar un programa que permita ingresar el nombre del
     alumno y una cantidad de notas por teclado y posteriormente 
     nos muestre la suma de los valores ingresados y su promedio.
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombre;
        int notas=1,promedio=0;

        Scanner run=new Scanner(System.in);
        while( notas >=0){
            notas ++;
            System.out.print("Ingrese su nombre :");
            nombre=run.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Ingrese el N° DE NOTAS :");
            notas=run.nextInt();            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías explicar tu código?? además cual es el problema que tienes?

Comment: quisiera saber si esta bien el como lo estoy realizando

Comment: es con el bucle while

Comment: Esta algo bien, es preferible hacer `notas++` al final de todo (cosas que se ejecutan en el `while`), por otra parte cuando para tu bucle??

Comment: Desarrollar un programa que permita ingresar el nombre del
     alumno y una cantidad de notas por teclado y posteriormente 
     nos muestre la suma de los valores ingresados y su promedio.

Comment: como lo haria para que salga promedio y la notas salgan tambien

Comment: Si lo que quieres es guardar las notas es mejor hacerlo en un array, también veo que reemplazas la variable `notas`, ten tus variables separadas (por un lado las de control y por otro las de almacenamiento o estructuras de datos)

Comment: ten un array llamado `notas` donde almacenes cada nota ingresada en el `while`, rompe el `while` cuando el usuario ingrese 0. Ponle un nombre distinto a la variable que recibe el input del usuario

Comment: y tu como lo haria ese problema que me han dejado

Comment: si [editaras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/468261/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo más detalles, tal vez de una respuesta

Comment: y porque no me puede ayudar por favor

Comment: Porque aca no hacemos tareas dieguex, pero si te ayudamos si tenes un problema puntual... Y aca, no se sabe cual es tu problema.. usa el boton [edit] y agrega tu problema en la pregunta....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo una posible forma de hacerlo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //variable string para el nombre
    String nombre;
    //variables para numero de notas, suma de notas, promedio y contador
    int nNotas = 0, sumaNotas = 0, promedio = 0, contador = 0;

    Scanner run = new Scanner(System.in);
    //pedimos el nombre
    System.out.print("Ingrese su nombre :");
    nombre = run.nextLine();
    //pedimos el número de notas
    System.out.print("Ingrese el N° DE NOTAS :");
    nNotas = run.nextInt(); 
    //Creamos el array de notas
    int[] notas = new int[nNotas];
    //mientras ese número de notas sea distinto de cero, entra en el bucle
    while( nNotas != 0){           
        //pedimos la nota
        System.out.print("Ingrese la nota " + (contador + 1) + ":");
        //almacenmos las notas en el array
        notas[contador] = run.nextInt();
        //sumamos las notas que vamos teniendo
        sumaNotas += notas[contador];
        //hayamos el promedio (Contador lo tenemos a cero, así que le sumamos 1, pues es la primera nota del número de notas)
        promedio = sumaNotas / (contador + 1);
        //incrementamos el contador
        contador++;
        //restamos una nota
        nNotas --;
        //damos el resultado nota por nota
        //System.out.print("El alumno " + nombre + " de " + contador + " notas, tiene un promedio de " + promedio + ".\n");       
    }
    //mostramos las notas del alumno
    System.out.print("Las notas de " + nombre + " son: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < (contador -1); i++){
        //mostramos todas las notas seguidas de coma, menos la última
        System.out.print(notas[i] + ", ");
    }
    //mostramos la última nota
    System.out.print(notas[contador -1]);
    //damos un línea en blanco
    System.out.println("");
    //damos el resultado al final, después de meter todas las notas
    System.out.println("El alumno " + nombre + " de " + contador + " notas, tiene un promedio de " + promedio + ".\n");       
}
```

El bucle bien se puede hacer con tel ejemplo que puse, o bien en lugar de aumentar el contador y disminuir notas, aprovechar el contador y eliminar la variable nNotas en el bucle:

```
//mientras contador, que va aumentando en cada iteración, sea distinto del número de notas
while(contador != nNotas)
```

Comment: creo que sería mejor calcular el promedio al finalizar el bucle y no hacerlo en cada iteración

Comment: Si @Christian, tienes razón, pero lo había puesto así, en plan instructivo, para que fuese viendo los cambios en los cáluclos que realiza el bucle en cada iteración, al igual que la expresión del bucle usando dos variables, una aumentando y la otra disminuyendo cuando se podría hacer perfectamente con una como muestro ahora en la edición de mi respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: gracias por la ayuda es que soy nuevo y resien estoy iniciando - el.trasgu

Comment: @dieguex, si te sirvió la respuesta, dale al check para aceptarla y así que pueda figurar como respuesta aceptada. Un saludo